# Is there any good reason to use Json instead of obj for Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm using threejs to load a 3D object. There are different loaders, one is using JSON files and other using OBJ files. 
I was wondering if there is any benefit in using JSON (example 1) instead of OBJ files (example 2).

```
Example1 loading JSON:

var loader = new THREE.PlayCanvasLoader();
                loader.load( './models/playcanvas/hand.json', function ( model ) {...

Example2 loading OBJ:
                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
                loader.load( 'obj/brain.obj', function ( object ) {...
```

Comment: In my opinion, it is often good to use something broadly used by other people as well. JSON is universally used. It is easily parsed by many other languages. Even this moment, I do not know about `.obj` file format so I would prefer to get `.json` file from you if needed.

Comment: OBJ is a format for 3D models. JSON is universal _as a syntax_, but it isn't a 3D model format by itself. Here, PlayCanvas uses JSON to store PlayCanvas data. If your workflow is closely tied to PlayCanvas, it might make sense to use that, but in the 3D world OBJ is more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three criteria when choosing a format:

1. *Features*. OBJ (Wavefront) is an older format, and doesn't support many features like animation, PBR materials, lights, cameras, etc. I'm not familiar with the PlayCanvas JSON format, but it probably does more things.
2. *Workflow*. Depending on where you're getting models and how (or if) you plan to update them, certain formats are easier and less bug-prone to export. For example, Autodesk software lends itself to exporting FBX. If you have something that works, feel free to stick with it.
3. *Performance*. Certain formats can be loaded more quickly than others. OBJ is probably on the slower end here. But the runtime performance of the scene — after the model has loaded — will be the same regardless, so this isn't always a problem.

Also note that three.js supports multiple JSON formats. `THREE.JSONLoader` and `THREE.ObjectLoader` both accept different types of JSON than `THREE.PlayCanvasLoader`. These JSON formats work fine in three.js, but will be harder to import and edit in modeling tools like Maya or Blender.